# cannot keep a stable session open with bloomberg blpapi Python

Tags: python, session, connectivity, bloomberg, blpapi

I recently encountered an issue that I have not been able to solve, despite calling the Bloomberg helpdesk and researching thoroughly the internet for similar cases.

In short, I am using the official Python blpapi from Bloomberg (https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python) and now am experiencing some connectivity issue: I cannot leave a session opened.

Here is the code I am running: https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python/blob/master/examples/SimpleHistoryExample.py

I simply added a "while True loop" and a "time.sleep" in it so that I can keep the session open and refresh my data every 30 seconds (this is my use case).

This use to run perfectly fine for days, however, since last Friday, I am now getting those log messages:

```
22FEB2021_08:54:18.870 29336:26880 WARN blpapi_subscriptionmanager.cpp:7437 blpapi.session.subscriptionmanager.{1} Could not find a service for serviceCode: 90. 

22FEB2021_08:54:23.755 29336:26880 WARN blpapi_platformcontroller.cpp:377 blpapi.session.platformcontroller.{1} Connectivity lost, no connected endpoints. 

22FEB2021_08:54:31.867 29336:26880 WARN blpapi_platformcontroller.cpp:344 blpapi.session.platformcontroller.{1} Connectivity restored. 

22FEB2021_08:54:32.731 29336:26880 WARN blpapi_subscriptionmanager.cpp:7437 blpapi.session.subscriptionmanager.{1} Could not find a service for serviceCode: 90.
```

which goes on and on and on, along with those responses as well:

```
SessionConnectionDown = {
    server = "localhost:8194"
}

ServiceDown = {
    serviceName = "//blp/refdata"
    servicePart = {
        publishing = {
        }
    }
}

SessionConnectionUp = {
    server = "localhost:8194"
    encryptionStatus = "Clear"
    compressionStatus = "Uncompressed"
}

ServiceUp = {
    serviceName = "//blp/refdata"
    servicePart = {
        publishing = {
        }
    }
}
```

I still can pull the data from the bloomberg API: I see the historical data request results just fine. However:

1. Those service/session status messages messes up my code (I could still ignore them)
2. For some reason the connect/reconnect also messes my Excel BBG in the background and prevent me from using the BBG excel add-in at all! I now have those "#N/A Connection" outputs in all of my workbooks using bloomberg formulas.
   [screenshot from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC6kG.png)

Has anyone ever encountered such cases? If yes, please do not hesitate to share your experience, any help is more than appreciated!

Wishing you all a great day,

Adrien

Comment: Are you connecting from 2 different locations or devices? You could get that error if you run your program on a PC and then open Bloomberg on a mobile for example. Other than that, you could to monitor disconnections and reconnect as and when required. Or your can use the session options and add the auto reconnect option (can't remember the exact name).

Comment: In Java: `sessionOptions.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(true)`

Comment: @assylias The issue seemed to have indeed appeared the second I logged to BBG on my phone while the python program was running! Haven't logged on my mobile since then but still have the bug. Is there a way to "kill" a session somewhere?

Comment: trying the sessionOptions.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(true) in Python. Will let you know. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If you login on the PC again it will "kill" all other existing sessions. Just make sure you don't open the app on your mobile, even for messages etc.

Comment: Seems like none of the above is working... logged out of the phone and back in the PC... will kill bbg for the next 12 hours on all platform and we ll see. Thanks so much for your advices

Comment: if you use `xbbg`, it will try to reconnect to Bloomberg every time before it makes a new query. There's no need to worry about connections in IPython / Jupyter kernel.

Comment: Hey @assylias, tried several sign in/logoff from BBG terminal, phone etc... BBG helpdesk is useless and confirms I have only one session running at a time. But the issue must come from here as it perfectly coincides with the moment I sign in on my phone (for the first time in a long time)

Comment: @Alpha I am not using any third party packages but the native requests. However, this i what I am going to do. Connect and disconnect for every single request. I gave up the idea of having a live feed at this point... Thank you so much for your help guys, will keep u tuned if any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet so I will try to "answer" it. I use blpapi everyday and pull data all day. I am a BBG Anywhere user and never have any session issues. If you log in from a different device it will kill your session for the Python app. Once you log back in where the python app is running it will connect again.

Why do you have another while loop and sleep to keep the session alive? You should create a separate session and always call it to run your request. You should not need any "keep alive" code inside the request. Just don't call session.stop(). This is what I ended up doing after much trial and error from not knowing what to do.

I run my model using Excel, trying to move away from any substantial code in Excel and use it as a GUI until I can migrate to a custom GUI. I also have BDP functions in my Excel and they work fine.

```
import blpapi
# removed optparse because it is deprecated.
from argparse import ArgumentParser

SERVICES = {}

def parseCmdLine():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Retrieve reference data.')
    parser.add_argument('-a',
                      '--ip',
                      dest='host',
                      help='server name or IP (default: %(default)s)',
                      metavar='ipAddress',
                      default='localhost')
    parser.add_argument('-p',
                      dest='port',
                      type=int,
                      help='server port (default: %(default)s)',
                      metavar='tcpPort',
                      default=8194)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args

def start_session():
    """Standard session for synchronous refdata requests. Upon creation
    the obj is held in SERVICES['session'].

    Returns:
        obj: A session object.
    """
    args = parseCmdLine()

    # Fill SessionOptions
    sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    sessionOptions.setServerHost(args.host)
    sessionOptions.setServerPort(args.port)

    # Create a Session
    session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

    # Start a Session
    session.start()

    SERVICES['session'] = session

    return SERVICES['session']

def get_refDataService():
    """Create a refDataService object for functions to use. Upon creation
    it is held in SERVICES['refDataService'].

    Returns:
        obj: refDataService object.
    """
    # return the session and request because requests need session.send()
    global SERVICES
    if 'session' not in SERVICES:
        start_session()
        session = SERVICES['session']
        # Check for SERVICES['refdata'] not needed because start_session()
        # is called by this function and start_session() is never called on its own.
        session.openService("//blp/refdata")
        refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
        SERVICES['refDataService'] = refDataService
    
    session = SERVICES['session']
    refDataService = SERVICES['refDataService']
    print('get_refDataService called. Curious when this is called.')
    return session, refDataService

# sample override request
def ytw_oride_muni(cusip_dict):
    """Requests the Price To Worst for a dict of cusips and Yield To Worst values.
    The dict must be {'cusip' : YTW}. Overrides apply to each request, so this
    function is designed for different overrides for each cusip. Although they could
    all be the same as that is not a restriction.
    Returns: Single level nested dict
    {'cusip Muni': {'ID_BB_SEC_NUM_DES': 'val', 'PX_ASK': 'val1', 'YLD_CNV_ASK': 'val2'}}
    """
    session, refDataService = get_refDataService()

    fields1 = ["ID_BB_SEC_NUM_DES", "PX_ASK", "YLD_CNV_ASK"]

    try:
        values_dict = {}
        # For different overrides you must send separate requests.
        # This loops and creates separate messages.
        for cusip, value in cusip_dict.items():

            request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")

            # append security to request
            request.getElement("securities").appendValue(f"{cusip} Muni")

            # append fields to request
            request.getElement("fields").appendValue(fields1[0])
            request.getElement("fields").appendValue(fields1[1])
            request.getElement("fields").appendValue(fields1[2])

            # add overrides
            overrides = request.getElement("overrides")
            override1 = overrides.appendElement()
            override1.setElement("fieldId", "YLD_CNV_ASK")
            override1.setElement("value", f"{value}")

            session.sendRequest(request)

            # Process received events
            while(True):
                # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
                ev = session.nextEvent(500)
                # below msg.messageType == ReferenceDataResponse
                for msg in ev:
                    if msg.messageType() == "ReferenceDataResponse":
                        if msg.hasElement("responseError"):
                            print(msg)
                        if msg.hasElement("securityData"):
                            data = msg.getElement("securityData")
                            num_cusips = data.numValues()
                            for i in range(num_cusips):
                                sec = data.getValue(i).getElement("security").getValue()
                                try:
                                    des = data.getValue(i).getElement("fieldData").getElement("ID_BB_SEC_NUM_DES").getValue()
                                except:
                                    des = None
                                try:
                                    ptw = data.getValue(i).getElement("fieldData").getElement("PX_ASK").getValue()
                                except:
                                    ptw = None
                                try:
                                    ytw = data.getValue(i).getElement("fieldData").getElement("YLD_CNV_ASK").getValue()
                                except:
                                    ytw = None
                                
                                values = {'des': des, 'ptw': ptw, 'ytw': ytw}
                # Response completly received, so we could exit
                if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                    values_dict.update({sec: values})
                    break

    finally:
        # Stop the session
        # session.stop()

        return values_dict
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your help on this! The "while True loop + sleep" is not used to keep the session alive: I start the session once (pretty much like you are doing) and then pull data from it every 30 secs. Testing your above code yields the same issues, with, or without a while True loop.
Using: 
`if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {"56045RT5":0.4/100}
    print(ytw_oride_muni(data))` 
I noticed that I am the only one on my desk with those session errors. All of my codes run just fine on my colleague's PCs. I definitely think that I somehow bugged out my BBG session forever...

Comment: @aleolux did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @evan54 unfortunately never did. Reached out to BBG, no helpful answers. There was obivously something wrong going on with my sessions/session manager. I ended up doing some nasty error management in python to avoid the code to crash and waiting for reconnects. Will not have the answer. (I resigned!)